# Como inserir um contador social no meu site?

Tags: api, contador

> Gostaria de inserir um contador social no meu site, porém *não quero nada de serviços externos* (que usem `iframes` por exemplo), como o ShareHolic.

Quero algo mais interno, via `API` ou algo do tipo.

Alguém tem alguma dica de como fazer isso?

Obs: Não uso nenhum CMS, apenas um pequeno site feito em PHP.

Comment: Tens alguma base de dados no site?

Comment: Não............

Comment: Estou criando o site em localhost :)

Comment: @Sergio eu achei um exemplo:  https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302
Porém não sei como adaptá-lo :/

Comment: Achei algo interessante: http://sharrre.com/#demos

Comment: @AlexandreLopes esse ultimo link parece ser bem simples, tenta integrar ele e posta aqui se deu tudo certo.

Comment: Sim, funcionou perfeitamente! Porém tive que fazer algumas configurações para os wisgets aparecerem em português, mas o plugin é show!

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, por que não pulica sua resposta? Ela pode servir de ajuda para outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo questionamento.